# MQTTnet TLS connection

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, mqtt, aws-iot

after some research I have finally got a working piece of code to send a MQTT message  to a test mosquitto MQTT server

```
var mqttClient = factory.CreateMqttClient();

var options = new MqttClientOptionsBuilder()
                 .WithTcpServer("test.mosquitto.org", 1883)
                 .WithClientId("client123")
                 .Build();

await mqttClient.ConnectAsync(options);

Main account = new Account
{
    Email = "test@example.com",
    Active = true,
    CreatedDate = new DateTime(2013, 1, 20, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc),
    Roles = new List<string>
    {
         "User",
         "Admin"
    }
};

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(account, Formatting.Indented);

var message = new MqttApplicationMessageBuilder()
                 .WithTopic("MyTopic")
                 .WithPayload(json)
                 .WithExactlyOnceQoS()
                 .WithRetainFlag()
                 .Build();

await mqttClient.PublishAsync(message);
Console.WriteLine("press return to carry on");
Console.ReadLine();
```

My next step is to subscribe and publish to a topic on AWS IoT with TLS.

I know I must use (in the MqttClientOptionsBuilder)

```
.WithTls()
```

but Im unsure how to specify which certifate to use to authenticate with

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I would check their code, I have found and `Obsolete` method, that says it is replaced with [.WithTls(MqttClientOptionsBuilderTlsParameters parameters)](https://github.com/chkr1011/MQTTnet/blob/master/Source/MQTTnet/Client/MqttClientOptionsBuilder.cs)